# Admin gesture for full screen TV app

Tags: usability, interaction-design

I am making an app for use on a TV and it will show some content in full screen. That means there will be no "admin" button or "gear" icon to use to get to an admin area where the app can be configured.

However, I need the owners of the app/tv to be able to configure it.

I imagine using some kind of gesture which can allow access to configure the app. However, seeing that it is a TV, there may not be any access to control it using fingers, so the gesture has to be somehow possible to do with something as clunky as maybe a TV remote.

What do you think? Is a gesture the right choice? And if so, which gesture would be intuitive and indeed possible?

Comment: How is the app added to the TV?

Comment: "...so the gesture has to be somehow possible to do with something as clunky as maybe a TV remote." Why does it need to be a gesture instead of, say, navigating a menu using the remote's buttons? I've never interacted with a TV by using gestures, so I'm having difficulty understanding why this question is calling for it. I'm also confused as to why you're talking about "maybe a TV remote." What other inputs do your users have access to when using this TV?

Comment: Good question. Some things were implicit here. Many apps on TV supports another remote. For example, if it is on Apple TV, you can use the Apple TV remote to navigate in the app or even your phone. And most new TVs will allow the original TV remote to also navigate in the apps in Apple TV, but it would be clunky, because it just has directional keys and not any touch control or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use pause/play button of TV remote to display service menu over your full-screen picture. So you'll be able to use standard pause/play gestures.